# How can I get a wireframe with "rounded" circular faces?

Tags: modeling, wireframe

I'm currently modelling a soundbox and it has a grid in front of it with rounded holes.

How do I get it in Blender because I already tried with square faces and it worked but now I want with round faces.

[image: So it should be like that].

I've tried one method, where I simple inserted the faces individually and deleted them + subdivision modifier but that "wireframe" had large "outsides"(bad english) that didn't look like a wireframe in the picture. Pls help me, I would appreciate that.

Comment: An image texture with a color ramp should work.
To implement this:
- Smart UV unwrap the faces you want to apply the texture to
- Open the shading tab
- Hit add and select image texture
- Hit add once again and apply a color ramp, adjust it so that it makes the texture appear dark
- Connect the image texture to the color ramp and then to the base color of your material
- Connect normal data if the texture has it

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/color_ramp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstrating with a Plane Subdivided 20 times to show what's happening:

[image]

In Edit mode with Vertex select (1 on the keyboard), select <kbd>Face</kbd> > <kbd>Poke Faces</kbd> **twice**:

[image]

Then select one of the centre vertices and go to <kbd>Select</kbd> > <kbd>Select Similar</kbd> > <kbd>Amount of Connecting Edges</kbd> which will select all the centre vertices:

[image]

Right-click and select <kbd>Bevel Vertices</kbd> (or use <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-B</kbd>) and pull out until you get the size you need. - Make sure that you only have the Segments set to 1 when doing this:

[image]

[image]

Hit <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>⌦ Delete Faces</kbd> and that's it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of Modifiers magic:

Add a **Mesh Circle** with the following settings:

[image]

Select the central vertex and add it to a Vertex Group named "Group":

[image]

Stack a few modifiers in the given order and play with the settings:

[image]